# Sennheiser EW 100 G3 (Lapel) - Good starting settings

Tags: voice, sennheiser, lapel, settings

Just wondering what people are using as their default settings for the TX/RX

Is this a good starting point for standard-scenario (i.e. Lecture, interview ... ):

Transmitter -21dB Sensitivity
Receiver -6dB AF Out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lapel Mics - Avoiding Spill from Multiple Speakers](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44620/lapel-mics-avoiding-spill-from-multiple-speakers)

Comment: Hello. Is seems to me that this question sort of duplicates https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44620/lapel-mics-avoiding-spill-from-multiple-speakers?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There are no typical settings to avoid spill. The way you avoid spill is to get the lav placement right. The closer to the source of the sound, the better to avoid spill.

Comment: If you set the Sensitivity low enough, do you find it sets a kind of noise floor below which other speakers voices are minimised?

If yes, is going below -21dB going to cause issues?

Can you counter these by increasing the AF Out?

Comment: This is not how sensitivity works. The noise you are referring to that will be generated in the transmitter is due to the preamps and the electrical components in the tx. If you reduce sensitivity to such a degree that you are "masking" off-mic signals, then you will have a very noisy target signal. Set the sensitivity to suit the desired signal source and the overall gain structure of your programme chain. Avoid clipping at the transmitter and then set the rx AF out gain to avoid clipping in the mixer. This is about as much as you can do with the G3